# Form to select column and free row

Tags: excel, vba

I must create a form to introduction number of ticket and other details to the Excel database in sheet. I have some code, but I don't know why target is empty. place, ticket, source is textbox, rodzaj is selector, okresod and okres do is date, godzinaod, godzinado is time. I send from form to the column, place = column A and first free row and other like below

I tried to edit some code, but it don't work.

```
Private Sub Wprowadz_Click(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xObszar As Range
    Set xObszar = Intersect(Target, Range("A6:U1350"))

    If xObszar Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = place.Value

    If xObszar Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Range("T" & Target.Row).Value = ticket.Value

    If xObszar Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Range("O" & Target.Row).Value = source.Value

    If xObszar Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Range("K" & Target.Row).Value = rodzaj.Value

    If xObszar Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Range("L" & Target.Row).Value = okresod.Value

    If xObszar Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Range("M" & Target.Row).Value = okresdo.Value

    If xObszar Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Range("Q" & Target.Row).Value = godzinaod.Value

    If xObszar Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Range("R" & Target.Row).Value = godzinado.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: It dosen't make any sense to repeat `If xObszar Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` over and over. Because if `xObszar` is `Nothing` then it will `Exit Sub` already the first time it hits `If xObszar Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` and it will never reach one of the others. So you can safely delete all of the `If xObszar Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` except the first one.

Comment: Your variables `place`, `ticket`, `source` etc are not decared. How are they defined?  How is the procedure `Wprowadz_Click(ByVal Target As Range)` called? Is this a button event? • Your question is very unclear because it is lacking too much details. I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: Wprowadz is button if form is complate it's introduce to table if row is free in line from A1:U1350, @Pᴇʜ

Comment: But a user form button does not have any parameters `ByVal Target As Range`. I think you are totally up the wrong tree. A command button click event should look like `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` where `CommandButton1` is the name of the button. No parameters! • Please also activate `Option Explicit`.